# Shell script to automatically run PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, bash, shell, plsql, dbms-scheduler

I have PL/SQL scripts and I was asked to make them run automatically using shell scripts. The problem is that I have no idea on how to do that, so please if there is any way to help me do that I will be thankful.

I tried to take the basics but it's far away from what I need:

```
output="$(sqlplus -S user/pw@//ip:1521/db <<ENDOFSQL
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
    v_return PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_return);
END;
exit;
ENDOFSQL)"

echo $output
```

Comment: You need a `/` after the `end;` (on a new line). But apart from that I have **no** idea what you are asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was asked to make them run automatically using shell scripts

At first place, why do you worry about automation of the script at *database* level. You could simply schedule it as a *cron job* at the *OS* level.

You could also schedule it at database level using `DBMS_SCHEDULER` or `DBMS_JOB`, whichever is applicable to your database version.

Comment: i'm forced to do it with shell script but i didn't know how to start

Comment: @Achref, just follow my answer. Is there anything else concerning you?

Comment: @LalitKumarB is there any tutorial that i can have

Comment: Tim Hall has some good stuff here http://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/cron-on-linux.php

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```bash
sqlplus -S user/pw@//ip:1521/db <<ENDOFSQL
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
    v_return PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello World');
END;
.
/

ENDOFSQL
```

There is no need to capture the output in the variable if all you're going to do is echo the output afterwards.

Comment: The question was: how to run a PL/SQL block directly from shell. He does not mention anything about scheduling - at least I don't see anything in his code.

Comment: Exactly what I want.